# How to map a 2d array in numpy?

Tags: python, numpy, data-science

I want to map pixels of an image to 0 and 1s. The pixels are stored in a numpy array like this:

```py
[[0, 255, 0, 255,...], [0, 255, 0, 255, 0, ...], ...]
```

I want to map this array to a new array which every element `x` of the new array is `f(x)`, which in here is `f = lambda x: 1 if x > 127 else 0`.

I was wondering how to do this in numpy and have not found a solid answer. I also want to know about when the dimension of the array increases, would the answer still work?

Comment: `(arr > 127).astype(int)`

Comment: I just do not understand how to apply that in multi dimensional array

Comment: That might work, but what about other functions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`np.where(myArray > 127, 1, 0)`

As for mapping an arbitrary function across a numpy array: there are a few ways but they all got downsides with performance and flexibility. The slow NumPy way is:

```
@np.vectorize # make f a ufunc
def f(x):
    if x > 127:
        return 1
    else:
        return 0

f(myArray)
```

Now, you can make it fast (even faster than the `np.where` because it doesn't go through the array's elements as many times) by using Numba:

```
import numba as nb

@nb.vectorize # also makes f a ufunc but it compiles f
def f(x):
    if x > 127:
        return 1
    else:
        return 0

f(myArray)
```

But as I said in my comments, the Numba version has issues with type dispatching; this easily becomes a problem when you're doing math on two arrays of varying numerical types. You're also restricted to the limited Python that the Numba compiler can work with; your example happened to simple enough to not need any edits.

Comment: Thanks, it will help in my current problem. But what about any other function?

Comment: So a function that "maps" or more accurately "broadcasts" across a NumPy array is called a *ufunc*. You CAN make a ufunc from a Python function on scalars with `numpy.vectorize`, but it's slow (NumPy's ufuncs are fast because all its scalar functions are in C). There are a few libraries for making fast ufuncs, but it either gets very unPythonic or heavily restricts Python. I tried out Numba before but I found that `numba.vectorize` has issues dispatching to intended types, so I ended up just using Numba to write simple loops that is tricky to do with vectorized NumPy.

Comment: If I am correct, vectorize makes a scalar function a ufunc which takes an array instead of a single item. But my issue is that I do not know how to extend that to a multi dimensional array (e.g. 2d in simple form)

Comment: It would be great if you could give me an example

Comment: Oh, a ufunc takes a NumPy array of any dimensions (1d, 2d, 3d, n-d).

Comment: yeah I can edit my post to write an example

Answer (score -1):

My friend, you can do something like this:

```py
def f(x):
  pass

uf = np.vectorize(f)
uf(numarray)
```

It will be applied to all elements. I tested it for 2D arrays as well.